# How Can I Check First Few Characters, Add Characters After First Few if First Few Match x in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to perform a three step process:

1. Check the first few characters (ffc) of a string variable.
2. If `ffc = x` (another string of characters) Then
3. Insert `x` after `ffc` but before any other content in `ffc`.

How can I accomplish this in PHP?

Actual Use Case:

I am using WordPress and grabbing `the_content()` and moving it into a variable `$content`.

I want some characters to appear before the text in $content, but WP auto adds `<p>` tags (if wpautop is on, and I'd like to avoid turning it off), which means the characters I add appear above rather than on the same line as `$content`.

The goal here is to check if `$content` starts with `<p>` and if it does to insert after `<p>` the characters "Summary: ".

Here is what I have thus far (it isn't working):

```
<?php
 $content = get_the_content();
 echo $content;
 $hasP = substr($content, 0, 3);
 echo $hasP; 
 If ($hasP == '<p>') {
   echo "Yes!";
   $newString = substr($string, 3);
   echo $newString;
 };
 ?>
```

Unfortunately, it seems that WP just re-adds the `<p>` when I echo $newString.

Comment: so if content read `<p>this is a line` you want the new string to read `<p>Summary: this is a line`?

Comment: and you only want to do that at the start of the line of content??

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 0):

So, this took a long time for me to figure out, but here is the solution I came up with (err, make that stole from other people):

```
<?php
add_filter('the_content', 'before_after');
$content = the_content();
echo $content;
?>
```

And then the actual magic happens here:

```
function before_after($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>/', '<span>', $content, 1);
    $content = preg_replace('/<\/p>/', '</span>', $content, 1);
    return $content;
}
```

In the above I actually went beyond what I had initially stated and replaced both the opening and closing `<p>`.